Confusion about a symbol in Chen's Linear System Theory and Deisgn
In pg. 123 of Chen's Linear System Theory and Deisgn 3rd edition, Theorem (5.2) states:

What is the expression after $\sin$? is this a typo?
Later he writes, again using this symbol:


I've figured it out. It means the argument of $\hat{g}(j \omega_0)$.
Let's denote $\hat{g}(j \omega_0)$ by $z \in \mathbb{C}$. In polar form, $z = |z| e^{j \phi}$.
I'll show that:
$$\sin (\omega_0 t) \cdot \text{Re}[z] + \cos (\omega_0 t) \cdot \text{Im}[z] = |z| \sin (\omega_0 t + \arg z)$$
This is true since:
\begin{align*}
e^{j \omega_0 t} z &= \big(\cos \omega_0 t + j \sin \omega_0 t  \big) \big( \text{Re}[z] + j\,\text{Im}[z] \big) \\
&= \big(\cos \omega_0 t \cdot \text{Re}[z] - \sin \omega_0 t \cdot \text{Im}[z] \big) + j \big( \sin \omega_0 t \cdot \text{Re}[z] + \cos \omega_0 t  \cdot \text{Im}[z]\big)
\end{align*}
and so we get:
$$\sin (\omega_0 t) \cdot \text{Re}[z] + \cos (\omega_0 t) \cdot \text{Im}[z] = \text{Im}[e^{j \omega_0 t }z]$$
and on the other hand:
\begin{align*}
e^{j \omega_0 t} z &= e^{j \omega_0 t}|z|e^{j \phi} \\
&= |z|e^{j (\omega_0 t + \phi)}\\
&= |z| \big( \cos (\omega_0 t + \phi) + j \sin (\omega_0 t + \phi) \big) \\
&= |z| \cos (\omega_0 t + \phi) \ + \  j |z| \sin (\omega_0 t + \phi) 
\end{align*}
and therefore:
$$
\text{Im}[e^{j \omega_0 t}z] = |z| \sin (\omega_0 t + \phi)
$$
which gives us the equality:
$$\sin (\omega_0 t) \cdot \text{Re}[z] + \cos (\omega_0 t) \cdot \text{Im}[z] = |z| \sin (\omega_0 t + \arg z)$$

That's right. Do you also know why the response looks the way it does?

@MattL. technically - the proof follows in Chen's text. However I have no intuition as to why this result is true.

It follows because complex exponentials are eigenfunctions of LTI systems. I.e., for $x(t)=e^{j\omega_0t}$ we have $y(t)=H(j\omega_0)e^{j\omega_0t}$, where $H(j\omega)$ is the system's frequency response.

A better symbol to have used would have been \angle which produces $\angle$.
